# caches_action undefined for controller in rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines, actionpack, action-caching

I've a Rails4 app a mounted rails 4 engine `MyEngine` with a controller `MyController`

I've defined multiple actions in the controller for caching as follows,

```
module MyEngine
   require 'actionpack/action_caching'
   class MyController < ApplicationController #inherits from application controller of app
       [:index, :show].each do |action|
           caches_action action
       end
   end
end
```

I've also included the gem `actionpack-action_caching` version `1.0.0` in my gemspec

```
spec.add_dependency "actionpack-action_caching", "1.0.0"
```

When I try to hit any route pointing to `MyController` I get following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError - undefined method `caches_action' for MyEngine::MyController:Class:
```

I'm using development environment so I have also changed the configuration for the environment to enable caching:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

I've tried changing a bunch of things like adding this block to `engine.rb` in `to_prepare` and `initializer` block.

```
ActiveSupport.on_load :action_controller do
    require 'action_controller/action_caching'
end
```

I've also tried setting `config.action_caching = true` in `engine.rb`.

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic, just not able to find out what!

**EDIT1**

Tried adding `caches_action` for an action within the application as well. It throws the same error.

To debug I added some print statements inside the `gem`

On this line [`require 'action_controller/action_caching'`](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching/blob/v1.0.0/lib/actionpack/action_caching.rb#L1), and it prints `true` when the server starts up.

Thats more baffling!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded to the latest 1.1.1 version of actionpack-action_caching, and it solved the issue.

Thanks to Andrew White who responded to the issue I'd raised on [Github](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching/issues/12).